# How to update Listview using ListAdpater

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

How can i use adapter.notifyDatasetChanged using ListAdapter. Please help me i got stucked in that code.All i want is to update the listview after  i edit the quantity of a product. Thanks for those who will help.

here's my code

```
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;

import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import org.json.JSONException;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.app.ListActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import android.content.DialogInterface;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.text.InputType;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.AdapterView;

import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.ListAdapter;

import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.Toast;


public class vieworder extends ListActivity {


    private static final String Edit_url ="http://192.168.56.1/editorder.php";

    private  static final  String Success="success";

    private  static final String Message ="message";

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private static final String Vieworderurl = "http://192.168.56.1/vieworder.php";

    public  static  final JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    private static final String TAG_POSTS = "message";

    private static final String TAG_ID = "Id";

    private static final String TAG_BRAND = "Brand";

    private static final String TAG_CATEGORY = "Category";

    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "Description";

    private static final String TAG_CODE = "Code";

    private static final String TAG_QUANTITY = "Quantity";

    private static final String TAG_UNIT = "Unit";

    private static final String TAG_UNITPRICE = "Price";


    private JSONArray order = null;

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> orderlist;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.vieworder);

    }


    @Override

    protected void onResume() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onResume();

        new LoadComments().execute();

    }


    public void updateJSONdata() {

        orderlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(Vieworderurl);


        try {


            order = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

            for (int i = 0; i < order.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject c = order.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);

                String brand = c.getString(TAG_BRAND);

                String category = c.getString(TAG_CATEGORY);

                String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);

                String code = c.getString(TAG_CODE);

                String quantity = c.getString(TAG_QUANTITY);

                String unit = c.getString(TAG_UNIT);

                String unitprice = c.getString(TAG_UNITPRICE);



                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_ID,id);

                map.put(TAG_BRAND, brand);

                map.put(TAG_CATEGORY, category);

                map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);

                map.put(TAG_CODE, code);

                map.put(TAG_QUANTITY, quantity);

                map.put(TAG_UNIT, unit);

                map.put(TAG_UNITPRICE, unitprice);


                orderlist.add(map);


            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    private void updateList() {

         ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, orderlist,

                R.layout.single_post, new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_BRAND, TAG_CATEGORY,

                TAG_DESCRIPTION, TAG_CODE, TAG_QUANTITY, TAG_UNIT, TAG_UNITPRICE}, new int[]{R.id.ID, R.id.Brand, R.id.Category,

                R.id.Description, R.id.Code, R.id.Quantity, R.id.Unit, R.id.Price });

        setListAdapter(adapter);


        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,

                                    int position, long id) {

                final EditText input = new EditText(vieworder.this);

                final  class EditOrder extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

                    boolean failure = false;
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        super.onPreExecute();
                        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(vieworder.this);
                        pDialog.setMessage("Editing Item...");
                        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                        pDialog.show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                        int success;
                        final String Quantity = input.getText().toString();
                        final String prodid =((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ID)).getText().toString();
                        try {
                            // Building Parameters
                            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("prodid", prodid));
                            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Quantity", Quantity));

                            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                    Edit_url, "POST", params);
                            success = json.getInt(Success);

                            if (success == 1) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(vieworder.this,vieworder.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                                return json.getString(Message);
                            }else{
                                return json.getString(Message);

                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        return null;

                    }
                    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        if (file_url != null){
                            Toast.makeText(vieworder.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }

                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(vieworder.this);

                alert.setTitle("Choose Option");

                //final EditText input = new EditText(vieworder.this);
               // alert.setView(input);
                //input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

                alert.setPositiveButton("Edit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {


                        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(vieworder.this);

                        alert.setTitle("Edit");
                        final String Quantity = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Quantity)).getText().toString();
                        final String ID = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ID)).getText().toString();

                         alert.setView(input);
                        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

                        input.setText(Quantity);

                        alert.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                if ((input.getText().length() > 6) || (Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString()) <= 0)) {
                                    Toast.makeText(vieworder.this, "Invalid Quantity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                }else{

                                    new EditOrder().execute();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                            }
                        });
                        alert.show();
                    }
                });


                alert.setNegativeButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // Canceled.
                    }
                });

                alert.show();


            }

        });

    }

  final  public class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override

        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(vieworder.this);

            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Order...");

            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);

            pDialog.setCancelable(true);

            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override

        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            //we will develop this method in version 2

            updateJSONdata();

            return null;

        }

        @Override

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);

            pDialog.dismiss();

            //we will develop this method in version 2

            updateList();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: May i know where you are editing your quantity of product

Comment: On the OnitemClick please read the code below

Comment: if (success == 1) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(vieworder.this,vieworder.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                                return json.getString(Message);
                            }else{
                                return json.getString(Message);

                            }

Comment: i want to change the Intent into adapter.notifyDatachanged

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are making a new adapter each time `update()` is called. Add the adapter to your instance variables, after all your `private static final` declarations, put

```
ArrayAdapter adapter;
```

so it will look like

```
....
import android.widget.Toast;

private ArrayAdapter adapter;

public class vieworder extends ListActivity {
....
```

Then move all the code below to the `onCreate()` method (from `update()`) and instead of making a new adapter just assing it to the adapter that is now visible everywhere in your class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.vieworder);

     adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, orderlist,

            R.layout.single_post, new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_BRAND, TAG_CATEGORY,

            TAG_DESCRIPTION, TAG_CODE, TAG_QUANTITY, TAG_UNIT, TAG_UNITPRICE}, new int[]{R.id.ID, R.id.Brand, R.id.Category,

            R.id.Description, R.id.Code, R.id.Quantity, R.id.Unit, R.id.Price });

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Then when ever you need to update, just write

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Originally you used a `ListAdapter`, which has no method `notifyDataSetChanged`. I suggest you use an `ArrayAdapter` instead, considering your data. [Here is the API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29).

Comment: But when i tried to write adapter.notifyDatasetChanged(); i always get an error Cannot Resolved method blahblah

Comment: @Paul Alright I fixed my answer. Problem was your adapter type. It was saved as ListAdapter, which has no such method. Save the adapter as SimpleAdapter, which has notifyDataSetChanged() method. So SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(...)

Comment: @Paul I Strongly suggest you change the adapter to ArrayAdapter altogether. Should be more suitable for your ArrayList and implements ListAdapter :) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29

Comment: Thanks but I'm new in android development .I will try to study that

Comment: @Paul Good luck! If this helped please consider accepting the answer

Comment: I find a better solution but it does not get the way i want to refresh the data in the listview instead of refreshing ,I use the intent to call the productlist  but first i close the same form and call it again

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems here is that you keep changing the adapter. You only need to set the adapter once. Here is a snippet of code to get you in the right direction.

```
private List<MyListClass> myList;
private MyListAdapter myListAdapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    myList = new ArrayList<>();

    //Setting the adapter here means it's only set once
    myListAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myList,
        R.layout.single_post, new String[] { TAG_ID }, new int[]{R.id.ID);

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);

    FetchListTask(new OnTaskCompletedListener(){
        public void onTaskCompleted(List<MyListClass> result){
            myList.addAll(result);
            MyListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }).execute();
}

public GetListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<MyListClass>>{
    private OnTaskCompletedListener onTaskCompletedListener;    

    public GetListTask(OnTaskCompletedListener onTaskCompletedListener){
        this.onTaskCompletedListener = onTaskCompletedListener;
    }

    protected List<MyListClass> doInBackground(){
        //Your business logic here...
        return list; 
    }

     protected void onPostExecute(List<MyListClass> result) {
        //Callback to notify your activity that the task is done
         OnTaskCompletedListener.onTaskCompleted(result);
     } 


}

public interface OnTaskCompletedListener{
    public void onTaskCompleted(List<MyListClass> result);
}
```